# Find a decomposition of Variance into difference and function

Tags: probability, summation, numerical-methods, variance

Given the two formulas for the variance:

$V_1(x)=\frac{1}{n-1}(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-n\overline x^2)$  and $V_2(x)=\frac{1}{n-1}(\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-\overline x)^2)$,

I've got to decompose in the manner specified,

$V_1=g_1 \circ f$ and $V_2=f \circ g_2$,

where $g_1,g_2$ are differences and $f$ is the same function in both forumlas. I've tried everything but it seems to me impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is just a modified square function, no? The first formula is a difference of squares and the second is a square of differences.

Explicitly, for the n dimensional vector $x$, 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum x_i^2$$

and $V_1$ is $f(x)-f(X)$ and $V_2$ is $f(x-X)$ where $X$ is the nvector, each of whose elements are $\bar{x}$